# Create a multicolumn table with latex

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

Can anyone help me to create the joint table?
the desired table is illustrated in the figure below.

Greetings

[image]

Comment: I can see no figure?

Comment: it is uploaded now, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always try to let https://www.tablesgenerator.com or https://www.latex-tables.com generate the LaTeX code for you. Sometimes it works directly, sometimes you have to edit the code a bit.